Colorizing spherical cap
I've drawn the following sphere in tikz.
\draw (4,4) circle (2cm);
\draw [dashed] (2.34,5.1) arc (180:0:1.66cm and 0.2cm);
\draw (2.34,5.1) arc (180:360:1.66cm and 0.2cm);
\draw [dashed] (4,4) -- + (-2,0) node [above,midway] {$r$};
\draw [dashed] (4,5.1) -- (4,6) node [right,midway] {$h$};
\draw [dashed] (4,5.1) -- (4,6) node [right,midway] {$h$};

How do I colorize the spherical cap as shown in the picture below


\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[orange!60] (35:2) arc[start angle=0, end angle=-180, x radius=2*cos(35), y radius=0.2] arc[start angle=180-35, end angle=35, radius=2] --cycle;
\draw (0,0) circle[radius=2];
\draw (35:2) arc[start angle=0, end angle=-180, x radius=2*cos(35), y radius=0.2];
\draw[dashed] (35:2) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, x radius=2*cos(35), y radius=0.2];
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (-2,0) node[above, midway] {$r$};
\draw[dashed] (0,{2*sin(35)}) -- (0,2) node[right, midway] {$h$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



You make a good point. I like how your solution preserves the properties I mentioned while using much less complicated code. I usually to it my way out of habit because that's how I always do it.

@Jasper: My code is only useful for a diagram like this. I draw h to the top of the circle and not to the "correct" north pole. -and the ellipse is not tangent to the circle, but merely has the same radius at that height.

My advice would be to go with an orthographic projection software. This is useful because it enables us to locate and size things correctly.
For example, it enables us to get the correct width of the cut. It also enables us to pinpoint the exact location of the north pole - which comes out at us when looked down upon in perspective.
My explanation is a bit more advances, but it will result in a more objectively accurate diagram. I thought it would be more useful that way.
I would use a combination of tikz-3dplot and the tikz library spath3.
Here is some documented code for my attempt:
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.2cm]{standalone}

% allows us to draw proper orthographic projections
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

% allows us to translate paths
\usetikzlibrary{spath3}

% sets the location of the intersecting circle
\def\Vt{35}

\begin{document}

% sets the view
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{0}

\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

% Main circle
\draw[tdplot_screen_coords] circle(1);

% Notice how we make the path near the origin, and then translate it using spath/save and spath/use
% Front
\path[spath/save=mypath,variable=\Vx,domain=180:360,smooth] ({-cos(\Vt)},0,{sin(\Vt)}) plot ({cos(\Vt)*cos(\Vx)},{cos(\Vt)*sin(\Vx)});
\draw[spath/use={mypath, transform={shift={(0,0,{sin(\Vt)})}}}];
% Back
\path[spath/save=mypath,variable=\Vx,domain=0:180] ({-cos(\Vt)},0,{sin(\Vt)}) plot ({cos(\Vt)*cos(\Vx)},{cos(\Vt)*sin(\Vx)});
\draw[dashed,spath/use={mypath, transform={shift={(0,0,{sin(\Vt)})}}}];

% Shade area
\fill[orange,opacity=0.3,variable=\Vx,domain=0:360,smooth] ({-cos(\Vt)},0,{sin(\Vt)}) plot ({cos(\Vt)*cos(\Vx)},{cos(\Vt)*sin(\Vx)},{sin(\Vt)}) plot[tdplot_screen_coords,domain=\Vt:180-\Vt] ({cos(\Vx)},{sin(\Vx)});

% The north pole
\fill (0,0,1) circle(0.06);

% dashed lines
\draw[dashed,tdplot_screen_coords] (-1,0) -- (0,0) node[pos=0.5,above] {$\scriptstyle r$};
\draw[dashed] (0,0,{sin(\Vt)}) -- (0,0,1) node[pos=0.4,right] {$\scriptstyle h$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


